# Permission model downgrade - Google Play Store new app version release

Tags: google-play

I am getting this error when i am trying to release new version of the app

[image]

I am getting the same error if i change the android-minSdkVersion to 23 also.

Help me out! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change to compileSDKVersion as follows :  *Remember to use the latest buildToolVersion with proper SDK Version installed .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
//        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    bu...
```